# How Do I Locate the Order Confirmation Email Item Renderer?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, custom-template, order-confirmation-email

I'm having difficulty updating the order confirmation emails that our site is sending. I can find and modify the template in the admin interface and I can find the corresponding items.phtml file in on the server, but I can't seem to figure out where the individual items in the order are being rendered.

The items.phtml file contains the line:

```
$this->getItemHtml($_item)
```

which, as I understand things, must be calling a function to render the item's HTML for display. I've looked everywhere I can think of, but none of the files I try are resulting in any changes in the resulting emails.

Location of the aformentioned items.phtml file:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml
```

A Few of the Files I've tried:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

app/design/frontend/default/myCompany/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml

app/design/frontend/default/myCompany/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

Comment: default.phtml file is rendered individual items.

Comment: Right, yeah, totally agree. But which default.phtml file? I finally found which one I needed to edit and it turned out to be: design > frontend > default > injoy > template > bundle > email > order > items > order > default.phtml. There must be an easier way than trial and error to figure out which default.phtml is attached to which items.phtml. Something has to route the request, but what?